# Magento 1.6CE layered navigation 'reset filter' missing href attribute (JavaScript location?)

Tags: php, javascript, magento

I have a problem on my magento layered nav, where the 'reset' function to clear the 'shopping by' filters does not work.

There is nothing showing in the console on click, the page just refeshes.

There is an empty href attribute in the anchor element which I think must be related.

```
<div class="actions">
   <a href>Clear All</a>
</div>
```

I have looked in the catalog/layer/view.phtml which the template hints indicate is generating the html. There is no reference to the div.actions.

There is however the following script call in the place I would expect this to be found

```
<script type="text/javascript">decorateDataList('narrow-by-list')</script>
```

Is someone able to tell me the location of the code this is referencing, and possibly explain what is going on. I'm okay with JavaScript but don't know Prototype- it looks like a call to a function although I would have expected it to end with a semi colon. Really I just need to find the file it references.

If this is unrelated, and I should be looking elsewhere for the the code that generates the link please tell.

Many thanks